# UTF-8 and HTML entities

Tags: php, utf-8

I try to eject text from Word .DOC file with PHP. All seems ok, but the only trouble is something like

```
&#x0421;&#x0423;&#x0414;&#x041e;&#x0412;&#x0410; &#x0411;&#x0423;&#x0425;&#x0413;&#x0410;&#x041b;&#x0422;&#x0415;&#x0420;&#x0406;&#x042f;
```

instead of russian text. I've tried to use html_entity_decode and utf8_encode, but they didn't help. Is there any simple solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) should work with the proper parameters (unless you’re using PHP 5.3.3 or later):

```
html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

This will convert the character references into UTF-8. Before PHP 5.3.3, the *charset* parameter’s default value was `ISO-8859-1`. In that case the cyrillic characters can’t be converted as the [ISO 8859-1 character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) doesn’t contain them.